# How to jump to the next external script in Oracle SQL if a previous external script fails?

Tags: oracle, error-handling

I send SQL scripts to a company where the operators run my scripts in TOAD. They have Oracle 10g. I am not allowed to create stored procedures, and I can send one script every day. Because I work on several projects, which have independent scripts, I send the main script like this:

```
@a.sql;
@b.sql;
@c.sql;
```

The three external scripts (say projects scripts) may be short or long, may call other external scripts, may contain PL/SQL blocks.

Normally, all my project scripts run, and I can get their result tables. But sometimes, some of my scripts fail. If a.sql raises any error, my script stops and doesn't run b.sql and c.sql.
In the case of an error, I want to stop processing the current project's script only, and I want my main script to continue with the next project script. If b.sql fails, too, then I want to continue with c.sql.

I tried WHENEVER SQLERROR, but nor EXIT neither CONTINUE does this. EXIT stops my script, CONTINUE doesn't skip the remaining part of my erroneous script (wasting a lot of time). I tried EXCEPTION in a PL/SQL block, but I could not call any external project script there. Is it any solution for this?

Comment: Use EXCEPTION in a PL/SQL block within each project script to allow a graceful exit of that script. Your master script (or any intermediate scripts) will then be able to handle the individual errors as they are raised and continue to the next project without interruption.

Comment: Thank you, it may be really a solution, but not a convenient one. We would need to rewrite all our codes, wasting a lot of time. I consider it.

Comment: _"We would need to rewrite all our codes, "_  Well, if you want your script to behave differently than they do now, which is what you are asking, you've got to expect to change things.

Comment: Well, something like WHENEVER SQLERROR GOTO would be less painful. We are talking about hundreds of thousands of lines of code. I still hope someone knows an easier solution.